# Gatsby hot-reload failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 on WSL2

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby

When running in debug mode, I think the hot-reload is failing to connect on 127.0.0.1, because (in WSL2) should be localhost. How can I change this to localhost?

[image]

How to solve this? I *think* that is a webpack configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `package.json` running command to:

```
"develop": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0"
```

Dealing with WSL could be tricky because of the running host and port since it's a subsystem in Windows. With the command above you are setting the host (`-H` flag) as `0.0.0.0`. Thereby, you can access your dev environment on other devices on the same network.

To access Gatsby on your local machine, use either `http://localhost:8000` or the “On Your Network” URL.

You can check for further information in [Gatsby-cli documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-cli/#preview-changes-on-other-devices) to polish your host and port if needed.